# How to reference the edited image to share it on social media?

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

I want to share the edited photo to a social media site after editing it using PhotoEditorSDK Android version, so I created a `shareImage()` function.

However I am not sure how to reference the edited image from the PhotoEditorSDK in the share function. Currently the code listed below I just add a dummy image of the image taken from drawable resources.

Also currently the share button I placed in PhotoEditorSDK photoeditor view keeps crashing on press.

```
public class PhotoEditorActivity extends Activity implements PermissionRequest.Response {
    private static final String FOLDER = "ArtCam";
    public static int CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SettingsList settingsList = new SettingsList();
        settingsList.getSettingsModel(EditorLoadSettings.class)
            .setImageSourcePath(selectedImagePath, true) // Load with delete protection true!
            .getSettingsModel(EditorSaveSettings.class)
            .setExportDir(Directory.DCIM, FOLDER)
            .setExportPrefix("result_")
            .setSavePolicy(
                EditorSaveSettings.SavePolicy.KEEP_SOURCE_AND_CREATE_ALWAYS_OUTPUT
            );

        new PhotoEditorBuilder(this)
            .setSettingsList(settingsList)
            .startActivityForResult(this, CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT);

        shareImage();
    }

    private void shareImage() {
        Intent shareIntent;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/Share.png";
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        path = file.getPath();
        Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
        shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "#" + getPackageName());
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the demo code here https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-android-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/photoeditorsdk/android/app/MainActivity.java

You have to wait for onActivityResult to get the resultPath

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, android.content.Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT) {

        String resultPath = data.getStringExtra(ImgLyIntent.RESULT_IMAGE_PATH);

        if (resultPath != null) {
            // Add result file to Gallery
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(resultPath))));
        }


        //TODO: Share the resultPath file 

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT && data != null) {
        String sourcePath = data.getStringExtra(ImgLyIntent.SOURCE_IMAGE_PATH);
        Toast.makeText(PESDK.getAppContext(), "Editor canceled, sourceType image is:\n" + sourcePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```